# How can I make ThingBoard's Entities Table widget default to a selected row via JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

How may I enable [ThingBoard's](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/) [“Entities Table” widget](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/ui/entity-table-widget/) to have one row selected by default (any row will do - of course, only if there are any entities to show to start with)?

This would be different from the default behavior which is for the “Entities Table” widget to have no row selected when the dashboard is refreshed.

I am looking for a hint about which object to manipulate when creating a custom widget based on the original “Entities Table” widget to achieve this behavior.

I have tried using the existing original widget to have one row selected by default but it seems this might only be possible to achieve by creating a custom widget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.